# Laravel fails to redirect when specifying URL

Tags: laravel-5

I want Laravel to redirect to '/dashboard' instead, Laravel keeps taking me to '/' after login.

**LoginController.php**

```php
public function redirectPath()
{
    return '/dasboard';
}
```

**Middleware**

```php
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) 
{
    return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected function authenticated()
 {
    return redirect('/home');
 }
```